# listing up files in a list file in 'last modified files last' order

Tags: command-line, bash

If I do `ls -ltrd *` I can list the files or directories sorted in the modified time order (recent ones at the end, because of the `r` option). Now I have a file containing list of this files or directories like this (by the way this list contains only files).  Suppose this is the file `list.txt`.

```
simab21m/sim_rtl_xmm_gemm_f32_spm_test_fpga/aa
simab21m/sim_rtl_xmm_gemm_f32_spm_test_fpga/ab_file_o.dat
simab21m/sim_rtl_xmm_gemm_f32_spm_test_fpga/bpad_40930.err
simab21m/sim_rtl_xmm_gemm_f32_spm_test_fpga/cds.lib
simab21m/sim_rtl_xmm_gemm_f32_spm_test_fpga/doctags
simab21m/sim_rtl_xmm_gemm_f32_spm_test_fpga/doctags_sw
simab21m/sim_rtl_xmm_gemm_f32_spm_test_fpga/env1
simab21m/sim_rtl_xmm_gemm_f32_spm_test_fpga/hdl.var
simab21m/sim_rtl_xmm_gemm_f32_spm_test_fpga/inc_list.txt
simab21m/sim_rtl_xmm_gemm_f32_spm_test_fpga/logx
simab21m/sim_rtl_xmm_gemm_f32_spm_test_fpga/makefileslist
simab21m/sim_rtl_xmm_gemm_f32_spm_test_fpga/scp_fw/abts.bin
simab21m/sim_rtl_xmm_gemm_f32_spm_test_fpga/sim_cmd.txt
simab21m/sim_rtl_xmm_gemm_f32_spm_test_fpga/sim_cmd/sim_cmd_defines.tcl
simab21m/sim_rtl_xmm_gemm_f32_spm_test_fpga/sim_cmd/sim_cmd_gui_fpga.tcl
simab21m/sim_rtl_xmm_gemm_f32_spm_test_fpga/src_list.txt
simab21m/sim_rtl_xmm_gemm_f32_spm_test_fpga/tags_sw
simab21m/sim_rtl_xmm_gemm_f32_spm_test_fpga/xemis_inc_list.txt
simab21m/sim_rtl_xmm_gemm_f32_spm_test_fpga/xemis_src_list.txt
```

I want to list up these files in reverse modified time order. How should I do it? I have tried

```
ls -ltrd < cat list
```

but it gives me

```
bash: cat: No such file or directory
```

or when I tried

```
ls -ltrd < `cat list.txt`
```

it gives me

```
bash: `cat list.txt`: ambiguous redirect
```

How should I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this [piping-the-contents-of-a-file-to-ls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44739947/piping-the-contents-of-a-file-to-ls) and here is my answer:

`xargs ls -ltrd < list.txt`

Comment: Note that if there are too many files or if the filenames are long enough, the final output may not be in sorted order.